# Upgrade SQL selection with checker numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**This is possible to add a *numbers checker*, to a query ?**

here is example in php (for all number)

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 70; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

or

```
foreach (range(1, 70) as $i) {
    echo $i;
}
```

**Here is query**

```
SELECT ticketnums.num, COUNT( ticketnums.num ) AS times, keno_tickets.gameid
FROM keno_tickets
INNER JOIN ticketnums ON keno_tickets.ticketid = ticketnums.ticketid
WHERE keno_tickets.gameid = (select MAX(gameid) from keno_tickets)
GROUP BY ticketnums.num
ORDER BY times ASC LIMIT 10
```

If some of numbers from 1 to 70 not exists in the results, so needed gives result **0 times** (if not found).

[**Here is DEMO http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a635c4/4**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a635c4/4)

Comment: You could probably use [CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard - i know what is CASE WHEN, but how it will help me here ?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure because you haven't included what your desired output should be but you can add a CASE WHEN range to the query if you need to limit something with other than a BETWEEN AND.